# How do I make a 500 - Internal Server Error Go Away When Generating an Excel XML file using ColdFusion?

Tags: xml, excel, coldfusion

I created a ColdFusion web page that generates an Excel XML file. Running on my local Coldfusion developer server it works just fine. This is running under Coldfusion 10.

The same exact file was on a Coldfusion 9 server running under IIS. 
Initially it was working there too. A week or so later someone came back to me telling me that it had stopped working. I looked at the Coldfusion Server's settings trying to figure out if it might be something there without any luck.

The file in question has:

```
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=demoFile.xls">
<cfoutput>... valid XML here...</cfoutput>
```

Again, this works on my local ColdFusion 10 Development server.

It did work on a regular Coldfusion server running on IIS.
It stopped working and now is getting 500 - Internal Server errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in solving this problem.

Comment: Do you have logs you can share?  Or maybe the code ?

Comment: In your browser, uncheck "Show friendly HTTP error messages" (IE) and you may get more useful info.

Comment: A '500 - Internal server Error' typically results from an error in your code. Since you have not provided any code to look at, all I can say is, to make the error go away...fix your code.

Comment: Is it possible the size of the file produced and being pushed out has increased dramatically?

Comment: I have observations that make me disagree with @ScottStroz.  When this sort of thing happens to me, it's almost always a java heap space problem.  This can be verified by looking at the exception log.  If this is what is happening to you, either add more memory or do something to limit the size of the file being produced.

Comment: @DanBracuk Plain old ColdFusion errors are returned to browser with a 500 status code, so, may not necessarily be a java heap problem and could be as simple as a typo. I make enough typos to know :D

Comment: This happens to me sometimes when I have data change on me.  For example you have a set of records that is interpreted wrong and jumps a column busting your generated page.  But this may not be the case, have you just clipped the header stuff and spun through the rest of the page to create output like a regular file.  I bet something will reveal itself if you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IIS 7.x+,

1. Open IIS Manager on the web server.
2. Click on the site
3. Double click the "Error Pages" icon
4. On the right-hand side click "Edit Feature Settings..."
5. Change the "Error Responses" to be "Detailed Errors".
6. Click OK

Run your page again to get a ColdFusion error message.  This should identify what is causing the problem.

Once you've fixed the bug, reset the "Error Responses" back to "Detailed errors for local requests...".

If this is a production server, it may be better to look at the ColdFusion log files to find the error.

Comment: This makes sense.  We've had the problem of contractors just deciding (without telling anyone else) that changing this setting or that is a good idea. Which, of course, is a Bad idea!